# How to plot stacked bar chart to summarise each categorical column for proportion of values

Tags: numpy, pandas, missing-data, data-analysis

I have a data frame like this:

```
    user_id     action          action_type     action_detail   device_type secs_elapsed
0   d1mm9tcy42  lookup          Missing         Missing         Windows Desktop 319
1   d1mm9tcy42  search_results  click           view_search_results Windows Desktop 67753
2   d1mm9tcy42  lookup          Missing         Missing Windows Desktop 301
3   d1mm9tcy42  search_results  click           view_search_results Windows Desktop 22141
4   d1mm9tcy42  lookup          Missing         Missing Windows Desktop 435
5   d1mm9tcy42  search_results  click           view_search_results Windows Desktop 7703
6   d1mm9tcy42  lookup          Missing         Missing Windows Desktop 115
7   d1mm9tcy42  personalize     data            wishlist_content_update Windows Desktop 831
8   d1mm9tcy42  index           view            view_search_results Windows Desktop 20842
9   d1mm9tcy42  lookup          Missing         Missing Windows Desktop 683
```

I want to set up a bar chart which has on the x axis the categorical columns e.g. `action`, `action_type` and `action_detail`, and on the y axis the percentage count (for each column) of the number of rows which have the values `Missing`, `Unknown` (you cant see this here but some columns do have that value) and `Other` (anything which is not `Missing` or `Unknown`).

One thing I am struggling with is also how to see, for each value in the `action` column, what is the % of the `action_type` and `action_detail` respectively that are Missing or Unknown. e.g. the action `lookup` occurs 100 times, and for these times 20% of the time there is a `Missing` `action_type` etc.

I have got somewhere with this via this type of code:

```
print("The percentage of missing action types is {0}".format
     (((clean_sessions['action_type'] == 'Missing').value_counts())/(clean_sessions['action_type'].count())
    ))
```

But I want to bring my analysis to the next level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get rid of the irrelevant columns.
2. Make all values be in `('Missing', 'Unknown', 'Other')`.
3. Call `value_counts`on each column.
4. The count will be `nan` instead of `0` when a value is not in column so you might want to use `fillna(0)` at the end.
5. You already have the data you need, just plot it.

-

```
result = (df[['action', 'action_type', 'action_detail']]
 .where(df.isin(('Missing', 'Unknown')), 'Other')
 .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True))
 .fillna(0))
print(result)

         action  action_type  action_detail
Missing       0          0.5            0.5
Other         1          0.5            0.5

result.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image: stacked plot]